# Bit manipulation to replace IF statement and improve performance

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, bit-manipulation

I can replace the following IF statement:

```
if(condition){
    x += y;
}
```

with:

```
x = x + ((y - x) * (condition));
```

to remove the branching.

Is there a way to avoid the above multiplication and replace it with a bitwise manipulation to make it faster?

Comment: Hold on, that doesn't seem right. Shouldn't it be `x + (y * (condition))`?

Comment: Most modern processors provide branch-free conditional assignment. Make sure you measure whatever "optimisation" you end up with to make sure you haven't slowed things down.

Comment: @harold You are correct. The OP code is equivalent to `if(condition){ x = y };`

Comment: hmm sorry, didn't notice **x `+=` y.**

Comment: @harold: BTW it should rather be `x + (y * !!(condition))` , to convert the condition (arithmetic) expression (if it is so) to logical `1` or `0`

Comment: On a 2's compliment machine, you can `&` with `-condition`.  But this sort of optimization is pointless (except for obfuscation) with a decent compiler, and in fact likely to make things worse.

Comment: It may be useless for optimization, but it does have uses for removing timing variance, which is useful e.g. in real-time systems and in cryptography.

Answer (score 10):

Do not do this without measuring your *application with the expected usage*.

### Why not.

Modern compilers already possibly detect and transform such patterns into conditional moves.

Modern CPUs speculatively run code "before time", which might then be faster than a complex bit expression; futhermore, there is a Branch Target Buffer which remembers decisions in local loops and then speculatively runs your code ahead of time, based on the BTB.

As said: Do not do this without measuring your *application with the expected usage*. Don't test on arbitrary benchmarks, which yield misleading (and thus costly) results most of the time. And of course, prefer algorithm and architecture optimizations instead of such microoptmizations; keeping code maintainable is typically cheaper in the longer term; don't build your business on undefined behaviour and highly specialized code:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/The_Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa_SB.jpeg/250px-The_Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa_SB.jpeg]

### Also.

Are you C or C++ wizard enough to verify the correctness of your "optimization"? Did you consider unsigned overflow und undefined behaviour w.r.t. signed overflow? Type promotions?

I *think* the answer is no, because you ask for help, yet don't realise the types used in your example are crucial but unmentioned.

Answer (score 9):

This kind of optimization will practically **never** improve your performance. Compiler does way better job at optimizing your code than you can do with such cheap tricks. Also in this case you in fact add more complexity to the code making it **less** efficient. A multiplication will always have to be performed and an addition will be performed.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(condition){
    x += y;
}
```

is

```
if(condition){
    x =x+ y;
}
```

so you can write it as,

```
x = x + ((y) * (condition));
```

only if condition is `0` or `1`. if condition can be any other value then this wont work.

```
x = x + ((y - x) * (condition));
```

is not right even if condition results in only `0` or `1` since it is equivalent to,

```
  if(condition){
        x=y;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Not so sure that you can beat an integer multiply. On some processors it takes a single clock.

Assuming a 0/1 condition:

```
x+= condition * y;
```

Alternatively:

```
x+= (- condition) & y;
```

Answer (score 1):

Before doing any attempts to evaluate you should add types for every variable. People may have different assumptions. Also my advice would be don't do that. Even if you get it right for now it will become a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score -5):

Make it one bit, shift it up to the sign bit, then shift it down with sign extension all the way, and you get either all-ones or all-zeroes.

```
x + (( y -x) & (((!!condition)<<31)>>31)
```

This is platform dependent, though.

Comment: Highly specialized, unreadable, undefined, highly platform dependent. Totally lacks explanation.

Comment: "shift it up to the sign bit" That is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it's a good idea, but it is what the guy asked for.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: Not in this case =) Assuming that you get sign extension (which you do on most platforms), you get the sign bit replicated all the way down - so either all bits zero, or all bits one.

Comment: `(((!!condition)<<31)>>31)` gives 1 only if it had the bit on otherwise it gives 0, please, edit.